# How to get the time when a notebook is saved and closed

Tags: notebooks, date-and-time

I want to get the time when a notebook is created and the time when the notebook is saved and closed, that is to say, the whole time when a notebook exist. What should I do? Thank you!

Comment: `NotebookInformation[]` might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some basic steps you could use.  Create a new notebook using this command:

```
CreateDocument[{
   ExpressionCell[creationtime = DateList[]];,
   ExpressionCell[Defer[
     NotebookSave[];
     NotebookClose[];
     closetime = DateList[]], "Input"]},
  NotebookFileName -> FileNameJoin@Append[
     FileNameSplit@$InitialDirectory, "new.nb"]];
```

Close the notebook using the created cell.  Then you have creation and close times.